# Different port Socket C# for sending and receive

Tags: c#, .net, udp, port, asyncsocket

i'm using UDP async socket in C#.net and i want to make the server and a client communicate in different port for sending and receive,

- the server send to client with port A and receive from client with port B
- the client receive from server with port A and send data to server with port B

is it possible??

Comment: What purpose does something like this serve? You would need two different sockets.

Answer (score 1):

In the client bind the socket to port A, and in the client bind to port B. It's as simple as that. The server shouldn't really know A, but get it from the messages it receives messages from the client (using something like [`ReceiveFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Remember that using UDP, the client *has* to be the first to send messages, otherwise it's not really a client-server system but more distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how it happens already. The source port for a client is a random port chosen by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this, since an endpoint consists of only *one* IP address and *one* port number. You would need to use two different sockets and establish two connections with the server in order to use port A and port B.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using TCP rather than UDP as part of the constructor of the [TCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx) you can specify which [EndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx)  you want the outgoing connection to use.